# Angular directive for temporary local variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

What I'm trying to do here is create a directive that allows me to set temporary variables that only apply within the html tag that I'm rendering.  The use case is something like this:

```
<div class="input-group" ng-local="opened = false" ng-blur="opened = false;">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="longDate" ng-model="start" is-open="opened" ng-focus="opened = true;" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" ng-click="opened = true;" class="fa fa-calendar" ></button>
    </span>
</div>
```

The idea here is that the ng-local directive creates a variable `opened` and sets that variable to an initial value `false`.  Everything inside of the directive is a transcluded template.  The benefit here is that I can have mutliple datepickers on a page, all who use the same variable `opened` without having to have a bunch of different variables all located on the scope in a controller that is only used as a temp variable for the content inside a div.  However, as this will be used in a bunch of different ways, I don't want to have to make a different directive for each use case.

My first attempt at this went pretty well.  However, I'm running into an issue where the parent scope variable `start` is not being accessed correctly from the datepicker.  I'm not very familiar with the $transclude functionality, so I'm hoping somebody can point me in the right direction.  This is the directive I've currently written:

```
(function () {
    angular.module('myApp').directive('ngLocal', [function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            transclude: 'element',
            replace: false,
            scope: {
                ngLocal: '@'
            },
            link: function ngLocalLink(directiveScope, element, attrs, ctrl, $transclude) {
                $transclude(directiveScope, function ngLocalTransclude(clone, scope) {
                    element.empty();
                    element.replaceWith(clone);
                    scope.$eval(directiveScope.ngLocal);
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
})();
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Here's a plunkr link

https://plnkr.co/edit/pog2bcxEf8mDEb2vIVjP?p=preview

Comment: could you build a plunker with the things you already have running?

Comment: @IgnacioVillaverde It's a bit complicated, but I'm working on it

Comment: I believe it would be of great help!

Comment: @IgnacioVillaverde Done!

Comment: Thank you, I am working on it

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$parent.localDate` instead.

```
<div class="input-group" ng-local="localOpen = false">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="longDate" is-open="localOpen" ng-model="$parent.localDate" />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" ng-click="localOpen = true;" >OPEN</button>
      </span>
</div>
```

If you don't want to use $parent you could use the isolated scope, and set the variable you want to use:

```
<div class="input-group" ng-local="localOpen = false" date="localDate">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="longDate" is-open="localOpen"  ng-model="date" />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" ng-click="localOpen = true;" >OPEN</button>
      </span>
</div>

angular.module('myApp').directive('ngLocal', [function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: 'element',
    replace: false,
    scope: {
        ngLocal: '@',
        date: '='
    },
    link: function ngLocalLink(directiveScope, element, attrs, ctrl, $transclude) {
        $transclude(directiveScope, function ngLocalTransclude(clone, scope) {
            element.empty();
            element.replaceWith(clone);
            scope.$eval(directiveScope.ngLocal);
        });
    }
};
}]);
```

Here is the forked plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/4zrNzbSc5IwqqbE2ISE1?p=preview

Comment: I was hoping to get functionality similar to that of ng-repeat where you don't have to address everything by the parent scope in the transcluded element.

Comment: @mrK Take a look at the edited answer, there you have other alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You not need *transclude* in your directive, just create [child or isolate scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-).

Sample

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);




// CONTROLLER
angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', function($scope) {


  $scope.dates = {
      workingDate : new Date(),
      brokenDate1 : new Date(),
      brokenDate2 : new Date(),
      localDate : new Date(),
  }

});



// DIRECTIVE
angular.module('myApp').directive('ngLocal', [
  function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      replace: false,
      scope: true //directive have own scope
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.1.0.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-controller="myController">


    <h4>This one works</h4>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="longDate" is-open="workingOpen" ng-model="dates.workingDate" />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" ng-click="workingOpen = true" >OPEN</button>
      </span>
    </div>

    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>



    <h4>This is the problem I'm trying to solve</h4>
    <h4>Both datepickers use "brokenOpen" so they both open whenever either is clicked</h4>
    <div style="width: 40%; display: inline-block;" ng-local>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="longDate" is-open="brokenOpen" ng-model="dates.brokenDate1" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" ng-click="brokenOpen = true" >OPEN</button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 40%;  display: inline-block;" ng-local>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="longDate" is-open="brokenOpen" ng-model="dates.brokenDate2" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" ng-click="brokenOpen = true" >OPEN</button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>



    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>

    <h4>This is using my directive</h4>
    <h4>The date does not update correctly to the parent scope</h4>

    <div class="input-group" ng-local="localOpen = false">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="longDate" is-open="localOpen" ng-model="dates.localDate" />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" ng-click="localOpen = true;" >OPEN</button>
          </span>
    </div>

    <label>See how the date is not updating: {{dates.localDate}}</label>


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this and it's still not updating the date on the $parent scope.

Comment: @mrK, yes, i missed this in your question. In this case, you should use _dot rule_ for ng-model

Answer (score 0):

Try nested directives. The outer directive encapsulates the data you wish to share, and the inner get the data from a function provided by the outer.

link to demo:
https://plnkr.co/edit/4n6kf40ZMf7lRCad5ofe?p=preview

The code:

```
angular.module('myapp', [])
  .directive('outer', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      scope: {
        value: '='
      },
      template: function(element, attrs) {
        return '<div>outer! value = {{value}}<div ng-transclude></div></div>';
      },
      controller: function($scope) {
        this.getValue = function() {
          return $scope.value;
        }
      }
    }
  })
  .directive('inner', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: function(element, attrs) {
        return '<div>inner! value = {{value}}</div>';
      },
      require: '^outer',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, parentCtrl) {
        scope.$watch(
          function() {
            return parentCtrl.getValue();
          }, function(oldValue, newValue) {
            scope.value = parentCtrl.getValue();
          }
        );
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

> I was hoping to get functionality similar to that of `ng-repeat` where you don't have to address everything by the parent scope in the transcluded element.

`ng-repeat` doesn't use **isolate** scope. It uses **inherited** scope.

For more information on directive scopes, see [AngularJS $compile Service API Reference -- scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-).

---

### Example

This custom directive transcludes its contents multiple times, each time creating a new inherited scope. The number of repetitions is determined by reading the `repeat` attribute.

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('repeat', function () {
    return{
        scope: false,
        transclude: 'element',
        link : function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transcludeFn){
            var parent = element.parent();
            var repeatNum = attrs.repeat;
            for(var i = 1;i<= repeatNum;++i){
                var childScope = scope.$new();
                childScope.$index = i;
                transcludeFn(childScope, function (clone) {
                    parent.append(clone);
                })
            }
        }
    }
})
```

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vvgvyfp9/)

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to do this?

Comment: Added example of a directive creating elements with inherited scope.